# AWS session timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Using AWS I have a lot of Chrome tabs open with multiple services. When I switch between them I am *constantly* getting signed out. Sometimes it's a matter of just few minutes.

[image: sign in again]

[AWS minimum session duration is one hour](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/userguide/howtosessionduration.html), so that's probably not the problem. How can I tackle this? Getting logged out of Lambda makes it lose all the undeployed code, this is very inconvenient.

Edit:

Answering the question in a comment: I do have multiple accounts and when I want to open a tab with a new service I just click *management console* (screenshot) and follow on from there. It appears to cause the actual logout.

But here's the thing - I am currently using resources **only** from the first account. So (since I'm within one account all the time) it shouldn't log me out right?

[image: AWS Console]

Comment: Did you check other browsers? Could be chrome issue, not aws.

Comment: @Marcin I will try and update the question.

Comment: I see this message when I use AWS one one Account, then login to a different account in a different tab. If I return to the original tab, it recognises that I am no longer logged-into the first account and asks me to reload. Are you logging into new accounts or perhaps using Switch Role functionality?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I updated the question.

Comment: That link probably generates a different set of temporary SSO credentials. Instead of using that link, select the service from the search field at the top of the console, then right-click the service and "Open in New Tab". That will open the other service in a new tab, using the same login credentials.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein this sounds like the correct explanation. If you post an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this message when I use AWS one one Account, then login to a different account in a different tab. If I return to the original tab, it recognises that I am no longer logged-into the first account and asks me to reload.

It seems that you are using SSO to login and it is generating a different set of temporary SSO credentials. Instead of using that link, select the AWS service from the search field at the top of the console, then right-click the service and "Open in New Tab". That will open the other service in a new tab, using the same login credentials.